# How does the container get passed to a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm attempting to understand someone else's code. They are using fragments (which I'm rather hazy on).

I know that a fragment starts up with `onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState` .. but I can't fathom where the "container" was set up.

where should I look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`container` is handled by the Android framework, it typically refers to View passed by id in methods like FragmentTransaction's [`add(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add%28int,%20android.app.Fragment%29) or [`replace(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment%29).

For example, this is from the [Developer's Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding):

```
ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_list, container, false);
    return v;
}
```

The layout `news_list` is for this fragment.

Comment: This doesn't answer the asker's question of "Where is the container setup?"  You're just showing how the container is used after it's passed in.  Consider revising to explain where the `container` variable comes from.

Comment: Your post doesn't answer the asker's question.  The down vote is to let others know that this post isn't helpful.  If the post is improved so that it answers the question being asked, I'll remove my down vote.